# {14.04 Elementary OS} sudo apt-get update - Failed to Fetch (Also Software Center doesn't open)

Tags: upgrade, elementary-os

Here is the output of sudo apt-get update in the terminal:

```
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise InRelease                             
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                    
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Sources                         
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                              
Ign http://debian.intergenia.de trusty InRelease                               
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed InRelease                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net sid InRelease                                     
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources                   
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam amd64 Packages                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net sid InRelease                                     
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources               
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam i386 Packages                   
Ign http://debian.intergenia.de trusty Release.gpg                             
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net sid InRelease                                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                       
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages      
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner amd64 Packages                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net sid InRelease                                     
Ign http://debian.intergenia.de trusty Release                                 
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages      
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner armhf Packages                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net sid InRelease                                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources                    
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net sid Release.gpg                                   
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net sid Release.gpg                                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources              
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net sid Release.gpg                                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net sid Release.gpg                                   
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net sid Release.gpg                                   
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources              
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net sid Release                                       
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net sid Release                                       
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages             
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources           
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net sid Release                                       
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources             
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources           
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net sid Release                                       
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages       
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net sid Release                                       
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages    
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages         
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages       
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages     
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages     
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages           
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en          
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en    
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en    
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Ign http://download.opensuse.org  InRelease                                    
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en      
Hit http://download.opensuse.org  Release.gpg                                  
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe amd64 Packages       
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/multiverse amd64 Packages     
Hit http://download.opensuse.org  Release                                      
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages              
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted amd64 Packages     
Hit http://download.opensuse.org  Packages                                     
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main amd64 Packages           
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Ign http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en_US               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages        
Ign http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en                  
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe i386 Packages        
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages          
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages      
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted i386 Packages      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages        
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main i386 Packages            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en             
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main Translation-en           
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/multiverse Translation-en     
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted Translation-en     
Ign http://download.opensuse.org  Translation-en_US                            
Hit http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe Translation-en       
Get:1 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [740 kB] 
Ign http://download.opensuse.org  Translation-en                               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en         
Get:2 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [356 kB]
Get:3 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [710 kB]  
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main armhf Packages             
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted armhf Packages       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Get:4 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [357 kB]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe armhf Packages         
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse armhf Packages       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted armhf Packages      
  404  Not Found
Err http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main armhf Packages            
  404  Not Found
Err http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe armhf Packages        
  404  Not Found
Err http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse armhf Packages     
  404  Not Found
Err http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe armhf Packages      
  404  Not Found
Err http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse armhf Packages    
  404  Not Found
Err http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted armhf Packages    
  404  Not Found
Err http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main armhf Packages         
  404  Not Found
Err http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe armhf Packages       
  404  Not Found
Err http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/multiverse armhf Packages     
  404  Not Found
Err http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted armhf Packages     
  404  Not Found
Err http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main armhf Packages           
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net sid/main amd64 Packages                           
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net sid/main armhf Packages                           
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net sid/main i386 Packages                            
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net sid/main Translation-en_US                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net sid/main Translation-en                           
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net sid/main amd64 Packages                           
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net sid/main armhf Packages                           
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net sid/main i386 Packages                            
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net sid/main Translation-en_US                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net sid/main Translation-en                           
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net sid/main amd64 Packages                           
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net sid/main armhf Packages                           
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net sid/main i386 Packages                            
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net sid/main Translation-en_US                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net sid/main Translation-en                           
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net sid/main amd64 Packages                           
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net sid/main armhf Packages                           
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net sid/main i386 Packages                            
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net sid/main Translation-en_US                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net sid/main Translation-en                           
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net sid/main amd64 Packages                           
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net sid/main armhf Packages                           
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net sid/main i386 Packages                            
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net sid/main Translation-en_US                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net sid/main Translation-en                           
Err http://debian.intergenia.de trusty/main Sources                            
  404  Not Found
Err http://debian.intergenia.de trusty/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://debian.intergenia.de trusty/universe Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://debian.intergenia.de trusty/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://debian.intergenia.de trusty/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://debian.intergenia.de trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://debian.intergenia.de trusty/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://debian.intergenia.de trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://debian.intergenia.de trusty/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://debian.intergenia.de trusty/restricted armhf Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://debian.intergenia.de trusty/universe armhf Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://debian.intergenia.de trusty/multiverse armhf Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://debian.intergenia.de trusty/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://debian.intergenia.de trusty/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://debian.intergenia.de trusty/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://debian.intergenia.de trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://debian.intergenia.de trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://debian.intergenia.de trusty/main Translation-en
Ign http://debian.intergenia.de trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://debian.intergenia.de trusty/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://debian.intergenia.de trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://debian.intergenia.de trusty/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://debian.intergenia.de trusty/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://debian.intergenia.de trusty/universe Translation-en
Fetched 2,163 kB in 26s (81.8 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-proposed/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-proposed/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-proposed/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-proposed/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://debian.intergenia.de/debian/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://debian.intergenia.de/debian/dists/trusty/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://debian.intergenia.de/debian/dists/trusty/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://debian.intergenia.de/debian/dists/trusty/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://debian.intergenia.de/debian/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://debian.intergenia.de/debian/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://debian.intergenia.de/debian/dists/trusty/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://debian.intergenia.de/debian/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://debian.intergenia.de/debian/dists/trusty/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://debian.intergenia.de/debian/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://debian.intergenia.de/debian/dists/trusty/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://debian.intergenia.de/debian/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://debian.intergenia.de/debian/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://debian.intergenia.de/debian/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://debian.intergenia.de/debian/dists/trusty/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://debian.intergenia.de/debian/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gregory-hainaut/pcsx2.official.ppa/ubuntu/dists/sid/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gregory-hainaut/pcsx2.official.ppa/ubuntu/dists/sid/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gregory-hainaut/pcsx2.official.ppa/ubuntu/dists/sid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/hunter-kaller/ppa/ubuntu/dists/sid/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/hunter-kaller/ppa/ubuntu/dists/sid/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/hunter-kaller/ppa/ubuntu/dists/sid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mjblenner/ppa-hal/ubuntu/dists/sid/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mjblenner/ppa-hal/ubuntu/dists/sid/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mjblenner/ppa-hal/ubuntu/dists/sid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/pcsx2/ubuntu/dists/sid/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/pcsx2/ubuntu/dists/sid/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/pcsx2/ubuntu/dists/sid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pcsx2-team/pcsx2-daily/ubuntu/dists/sid/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pcsx2-team/pcsx2-daily/ubuntu/dists/sid/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pcsx2-team/pcsx2-daily/ubuntu/dists/sid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

This is my /etc/apt/sources.list

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted 
deb-src http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted 
deb http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted 
deb-src http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted 
deb-src http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted 

###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner


###### 3rd Party Binary Repos

#### Clementine PPA - http://www.clementine-player.org/
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 044A3B98
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/me-davidsansome/clementine-dev/ubuntu trusty main

#### Dropbox - http://dropbox.com
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 5044912E
deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/ trusty main

#### Steam for Linux - http://store.steampowered.com/about/
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F24AEA9FB05498B7
deb [arch=i386] http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam

#### Wine PPA - https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa/
## Run this command:  sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F9CB8DB0
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu trusty main


####### 3rd Party Source Repos

#### Clementine PPA (Source) - http://www.clementine-player.org/
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 044A3B98
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/me-davidsansome/clementine-dev/ubuntu trusty main

#### Wine PPA (Source) - https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa/
## Run this command:  sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F9CB8DB0
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
```

I know it's a mess but I want help..

P.S My Software Center can't open, but I couldn't try the solutions i found online because the first thing they require is apt-get update.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a lot of 404s. That simply means those URLs do not exist. http://debian.intergenia.de is a Debian repository, as the name suggests and you easily verify by pointing a web browser to it. It doesn't contain trusty, which is an Ubuntu release. The Hash sum mismatch errors are easily fixed by deleting the relevant files in `/var/lib/apt/lists`. I think some of the other errors you're getting are because your chosen mirror doesn't have the armhf arch on it, I could do a more comprehensive audit of your sources, but just go to those urls yourself and check it out.